# Any large group is SQ-universal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, quotient-group

This result is part of the preliminary section of *"Largeness and SQ-universality of Cyclically Presented Groups,"* by Gerald Williams.

### The Details:

> **Definition 1:** A group is *large* if it has a finite index subgroup that maps onto the free group $F_2$ of rank $2$.
>
> **Definition 2:** A group $G$ is *SQ-universal* if every countable group can be embedded in a quotient group of $G$.

### The Question:

> Prove that any given large group is SQ-universal.

### Thoughts:

Let $G$ be large. Then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $[G: H]$ is finite and there exists epimorphism $\theta: H\to F_2$. Thus, in a sense, $F_2$ can be seen as a subgroup of $G$. This would be sufficient (almost) provided that the following hold.

- The group $F_2$ is SQ-universal.
- If $A$ is a subgroup of a group $B$ and $A$ is SQ-universal, then $B$ is SQ-universal.

The former isn't very clear to me but the latter seems obvious.

Please help :)

Comment: @EricWofsey: Just my luck, then!

Comment: Er, sorry, the former is not easy.  But it is true, at least.  I don't actually know a counterexample for the latter off the top of my head but I'm pretty sure it's not true.

Comment: Well, a third dot would be also needed: $\\$
 If a quotient group $A/N$ is SQ-universal, then so is the ambient group $A$. $\\$
*This* one is trivial from the definition.

As for the second dot, it's enough to consider the case when $A\subseteq B$ is a subgroup of *finite index*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theorem.** Large $\Rightarrow$ SQ-universal.

*Proof.*

1. The group $F_2$ is SQ-universal. This is an old result of Higman-Neumann-Neumann (in their paper where they first introduce HNN-extensions: [G. Higman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_Higman), [B.H. Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Neumann) and [H. Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanna_Neumann), *Embedding theorems for groups*, J. London Math. Soc. 24 (1949), 247-254).
2. Being SQ-universal is closed under finite-index (suppose $H\leq_fG$, then $G$ is SQ-univesal if and only if $H$ is SQ-universal). This is a result of [Peter Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_M._Neumann)*. The reference is [P.M. Neumann: The SQ-universality of some finitely presented groups. J. Austral. Math. Soc. 16, 1-6 (1973)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9DCB0BDA3B7BA5AE8EA07B5A7ABAC6C6/S1446788700013859a.pdf/squniversality_of_some_finitely_presented_groups.pdf). I have copied out the first direction of the proof, that if $G$ is SQ-univesal and $H\leq_f G$ then $H$ is SQ-universal, which unfortunately is not the direction you need. The opposite direction is longer; you can look at it in the paper if you wish. *The  proof   of  the  lemma  depends  on  the  well-known  fact  that  every  countable group  can  be  embedded  in  a  countably  infinite  simple  group.  So, let $X$ be any  countable  group  and  let $S$ be  a  countable,  infinite  simple  group  which  has a subgroup  isomorphic  to $X$. Suppose first that $G$ is SQ-universal and that $H$ is a subgroup of finite index in $G$. There will exist a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $\overline{G} = G/N$ contains a subgroup $\overline{S}$ isomorphic to $S$. Now $\overline{H} = HN/N$ has finite index in $\overline{G}$. Therefore $H \cap \overline{S}$ has finite index in $\overline{S}$ and consequently contains a subgroup which is normal and of finite index in $\overline{S}$. Since $\overline{S}$ is simple and infinite it follows that $\overline{H} \cap \overline{S} = \overline{S}$. Thus $S$, and consequently also $X$, is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\overline{H}=HN/N\cong H/(H\cap N)$. Hence $H$ is SQ-universal.*

Some remarks:

1. If $H\twoheadrightarrow F_2$ then $H$ actually contains a copy of $F_2$. So when you say "Thus, in a sense, $F_2$ can be seen as a subgroup of $G$", this is actually quite concrete as $F_2\leq H\leq G$.
2. There exist non-SQ-universal groups which contain an SQ-universal subgroup, so your second bullet point is wrong (that is, you *need* the finite index condition). For example, in the above paragraph from P. Neumann's paper it is pointed out that there is a simple group, $S$ say, which contains some SQ-universal group as a subgroup (e.g. $F_2\hookrightarrow S$). Then $S$ cannot be SQ-universal: to see this, suppose otherwise. By simplicity, every two-generated group embeds into $S$. There are uncountably many non-isomorphic two-generated groups. However, there are only countably many two-generated subgroups of $S$ (as there are only countably many pairs of elements $(s_1, s_2)\in S\times S$). This is a contradiction, and the result follows.
3. Large groups were first studied by Steve Pride. The first result was with B. Baumslag**, where they proved that if a group $G$ has a presentation with two more generators than relators then $G$ is large; later, in the early '80s, his student Martin Edjvet studied them for his thesis ("The concept of largeness in group theory" - Edjvet is still around). Steve once told me that his motivation was to get some sort of partial ordering on finitely generated groups based on SQ-universality, and in particular two groups should be equal in this partial order if they are commensurable (that is, $A\sim B$ if there exists $C$ such that $C$ embeds with finite index into both $A$ and $B$). The ordering on finitely generated groups is as follows: $H\preceq G$ if there exists $K\lhd_fG$ such that $K\twoheadrightarrow H$. This partial order is called the *largeness* ordering. Note that large groups sit at the top of this order, as $F_2$ contains with finite index free subgroups of arbitrary finite rank.

*One of the sons of the above two Neumanns - the result is in fact dedicated to "the memory of (his) mother", H.Neumann.

**Brother of the great [G. Baumslag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Baumslag).